# Generic Methods for Rendering TableColumns in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

So my application uses a number of TableViews within different FXMLViewControllers to present a number of different JPA Entities.   The example below is for JobSupplierParts.

```
    /**
 * renderDoubleColumn takes a TableColumn setting its value and type before setting up edit event handling.
 * @param column the tableColumn to be set up.
 * @param field the name of the field to be mapped to.
 * @param methodName the set method name of the field.
 */
protected void renderDoubleColumn(TableColumn<JobSupplierPart, Double> column, String field, String methodName) {
    String className = "BiasDB.JobSupplierPart";
    column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(field));
    column.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<JobSupplierPart, Double>forTableColumn(new DoubleStringConverter()));
    column.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<JobSupplierPart, Double>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<JobSupplierPart, Double> t) {
                    JobSupplierPart supplierPart = t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow());

                    try {
                        Class<?> c = Class.forName(className);
                        Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, Double.class);
                        method.invoke(supplierPart, t.getNewValue());
                        supplierPart.setTotal(updateItem(supplierPart));
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException|NoSuchMethodException|IllegalAccessException|InvocationTargetException ex) {
                        logger.error("renderDoubleColumn",ex);
                    } //End try to get method from String.

                    try {
                        jobSupplierPartController.edit(supplierPart);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        logger.error("renderDoubleColumn",ex);
                    }
                    t.getTableView().refresh();
                }
            } //END Event Handler
    ); //END SetOnEditCommit.
}
//END renderDoubleColumn
```

I can call this with:

```
renderDoubleColumn(discountColumn, "discount", "setDiscount");
```

BUT - I have to create new methods for each JPA Entity.    Is it possible to replace the references to JobSupplierPart such that it becomes a generic method much like I have achieved with the methods?   I have tried  and alternatives such as T or K but they all returned errrors.  The controller can just be passed as a parameter.   Or is this a really bad practice/poor performance thing to do?

Comment: that's terrible code (using reflection in quite normal contexts, calling table.refresh) - why do you feel like having to fight against fx?

Comment: @kleopatra.  Would you like to expand.  I'm keen to learn.   Just returning to Java after 13 year break into Python and PHP.   Why would you not follow DRY principals and have a method rather than numerous identical methods short of a few name changes.

Comment: @kleopatra.   Hi,  I don't know if you will feel that my now posted answer is any less terrible - I hope so!

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know if the Java aficionados will agree with this solution but in response to an answer posted and then deleted shortly after I was able to make the code cleaner.   I also moved the set/edit section into a method so now I have:

```
/**
 * renderBigDecimalColumn takes a TableColumn setting its value and type before setting up edit event handling.
 * @param column the tableColumn to be set up.
 * @param field the name of the field to be mapped to.
 */
private void renderBigDecimalColumn(TableColumn<AccountAsset, BigDecimal> column, String field) {

    //Set an observable value for the column
    column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(field));

    //Set how we want the cell to be rendered
    // This line varies for the different cell types e.g. Strings, Bools etc.
    column.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<AccountAsset, BigDecimal>forTableColumn(new BigDecimalStringConverter()));

    //Set how we want the cell to be edited including the row update.
    column.setOnEditCommit(t -> {
        handleEditCommit(t, field);
    }); //END SetOnEditCommit.

} //END renderBigDecimalColumn
```

And my handleEditCommit method looks like:

```
/** handleEditCommit deals with updating and saving the new data from the table view.
 *
 * @param t
 * @param field
 */
private void handleEditCommit(javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent<AccountAsset,?> t, String field) {
    AccountAsset rowData = t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow());

    //Set the new value.
    try {
        BeanUtils.setProperty(rowData, field, t.getNewValue());
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        logger.error("handleEditCommit / Setter", ex);
    }

    //Save the new rowData back to the database.
    try {
        tableDataController.edit(rowData);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("handleEditCommit / Edit", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Starting in Java 8 you can use method references, which is less error-prone than string-based field names, and provides compile-time checks (for types, name, access etc). Use either `Callback` or `Function` for getter, and `BiConsumer` for setter, and pass e.g. `AccountAsset::getDiscount` and `AccountAsset::setDiscount` ...  If you have FX-style properties you can just pass the property getter.